# Using ddl data in teiid

Tags: wildfly, jboss7.x, wildfly-10, teiid

Using jboss EAP 7 and  Teiid Designer 10.4 and wildfly 10.

I have DDL file of MySQL .how can I make  VDB using that.

Can I run it using teiid?

when I tried to import ddl data as Teiid ddl ,it showed parsing error,but the same was able to import as general ddl.

Answer (score 0):

Please take look at documentation on this http://docs.jboss.org/teiid/designer/11.1/user-guide/en-US/html_single/#ddl-import-section

and then select appropriate dialect while doing so.